# Notepad++ Trying to values that are below 1800

Tags: notepad++

I'm new to the advanced features of Notepad++ and math is not one of my strong points.

I run a DayZ server and in the configuration files, I want to find all lines where items restock values are below 1800.

In the file the data this looks like:-

```
<restock>1800</restock>
```

The max restock value is 3888000, so each line could have a number that is anywhere between 1 to 7 digits in length. However, I am just looking for values that are between 1 to 4 digits long.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, type:

- Find what: `<restock>(\b[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?\b|1[0-7][0-9]{2})</restock>`
- Search mode: Regular Expression

It finds restock tags whose number are below 1800.

- `\b[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?\b`: Find numbers from 1 to 999
- `1[0-7][0-9]{2}`: Find numbers from 1000 to 1799

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Reddy that works really well :)

Comment: @Kaity You can mark the answer as solved if your request has been met.

Comment: how do I do that? I cannot see any option :(

Comment: Please visit [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).